# How to return localized content from WebAPI? Strings work but not numbers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, localization

Given this `ApiController`:

```
public string TestString() {
    return "The value is: " + 1.23;
}

public double TestDouble() {
    return 1.23;
}
```

With the browser's language set to "fr-FR", the following happens:

/apiController/TestString yields

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">The value is: 1,23</string>
```

/apiController/TestDouble yields

```
<double xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1.23</double>
```

I would expect TestDouble() to yield 1,23 in the XML.  Can anyone explain why this isn't the case and, more importantly, how to make it so that it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the conversion from double to string happens at different stage for each API. For the TestString API, double.ToString() is used to convert the number to a string using CurrentCulture of the current thread and it happens when the TestString method is called. Meanwhile, the double number which is returned by TestDouble is serialized to string during the serialization step which uses GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Culture.
In my opinion, both should use InvariantCulture. On the consumer side, the values will be parsed and be formatted with the correct culture.

**Update**: this is only used for JsonFormatter. XmlFormatter doesn't have such a setting.

**Update 2**:
It seems (decimal) numbers need special converter to make it culture-aware:
[Handling decimal values in Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json)

Btw, if you want o change data format per action/request, you can try the last piece of code of the following link: http://tostring.it/2012/07/18/customize-json-result-in-web-api/

Comment: Ah, very helpful, thanks.  One point of clarification: if I set the culture manually on the JsonFormatter before returning the double, it still doesn't serialize it according to that culture.  Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @DuncanMack Sorry, that setting only works for JsonFormatter. I don't know of any setting that can be used for XmlFormatter which is the one you are using. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for JSON (...I'm returning JSON using content negotiation headers).  It's returning JSON, but still not localized despite setting the culture before returning the double.

Comment: Updated again :) After all, I still think all data should be sent in invariant culture format :)