# c# WebApi serialization of decimal

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, decimal

I have a WebApi Controller which returns a List. My problem is, that I do not want xxxx.0 in the resulting JSON as this makes serious problems in my javascript. Is there a way to prevent .net serialization with .0 values so that they get truncated?

Current output:

```
{"Temperature":[[1465434000.0,4.00],[1465437600.0,15.40],[1465441200.0,15.26],
```

Wanted:

```
{"Temperature":[[1465434000,4.00],[1465437600,15.40],[1465441200,15.26],
```

Object which is serialized:

```
public class ChartDataMonthly
{
    public List<decimal[]> Temperature { get; set; }
```

Comment: I assume you want this in a way that keeps the decimal if it's non-zero?

Comment: seems to me that its doing exactly what you intended. The value it serialized to is a decimal. Any consuming code shouldnt have any issues with consuming it as a float. Of course I dont have a good answer to your questions, you might want to look into custom deserializers. if I recall, the default deserializer for the later versions of .net is JSON.net. Should be easy to research.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is fine. It shouldn't make a difference to your client(s). The real question is why you would want this? For aesthetics? That really doesn't matter for an API response.

Comment: `as this makes serious problems in my javascript` <- This is what you need to address and not the correct serialization of a decimal. Can you post the code and the description of the error/problem you have with your script code and decimals?

Comment: The client is highcharts. It assumes the first value is a timestamp.

Comment: Check out this answer. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json)

Answer (score 0):

I guess where I would start is to create a new property on your object for your javascript model:

```
public class ChartDataMonthly
{
    public List<decimal[]> Temperature { get; set; }

    // This can be "unmapped" to ignore object mappers
    public List<string> RoundedTemperature 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Temperature.Select(t => Math.Round(t).ToString()).ToList();
        }
    }
    // rest of model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ChartDataMonthly
{
    public List<decimal[]> Temperature { get; set; }

    public List<decimal[]> Round()
    {
        List<decimal[]> NewTemp = new List<decimal[]>();
        foreach(var t in Temperature)
        {
           t[0] = Math.Round(t[0], 0);
           NewTemp.Add(t)
        }

        return NewTemp;
    }
}
```

I saw a new answer similar to this one get posted about two minutes before mine, but this is roughly how I would start. You can either use the return List or Json.SerializeObject and return the string by modifying the method slightly to return a string similar to @dckuehn's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ChartDataMonthly
    {
        public List<decimal[]> _temperature;
        public List<decimal[]> Temperature
        {
            get { return _temperature; }
            set
            {
                _temperature = value;
                //edit each value by reference
                _temperature.ForEach(x => x.ToList().ForEach(y =>y= Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(y)))));
            }
        }
    }
```

Untested but i think it should do the work automatically
You just round every field of each array in your list.

If you do it inside a setter/getter it will automatically do it when the .net binder bind the JavaScript to your object