# deserialize number with comma in json to decimal

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can't deserialize number with comma in json to decimal because comma is deleting, for example 123,99 is replaced by 12399.

I have found similar problem to mine:
[Handling decimal values in Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json)
but mine is easier because it is a standard number where dot is comma, I don't need parse using specific culture. How can I do that?

```
public class PriceModel
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{'Price': '1234,99'}";
PriceModel priceModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceModel>(json);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's about current thread culture.

`en-US` separator is `.`

```
PriceModel value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceModel>("{'Price': '1234,99'}", new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // tr culture separator is ","..
    Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR")  //Replace tr-TR by your own culture
});
```

and check this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/3ebe5aks(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396