# Set default serializer/deserializer

Tags: asp.net-core, serialization, json.net, .net-5

In my `Startup.cs` i have set up my default serializer with options like this

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.UseMemberCasing();
    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
    options.SerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Double;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    options.SerializerSettings.TraceWriter = new NLogTraceWriter();                    
    options.SerializerSettings.Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;                    

    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => options.SerializerSettings;
});
```

and expected anything returned from Action or coming to Action as a parameter to be serialized (or deserialized) using this setting, which is not the case. This setting only gets used when i explicitly use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method. Is there anything else I need to set up so I don't have to use these functions explicitly in every action?

Can anyone please enlighten me on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, please share a [mcve] showing the JSON you need to parse that uses commas for a decimal separator.  [How to localize when JSON-serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4721143/3744182) and [deserialize number with comma in json to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42401151/3744182) look most closely related.

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm), `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` are used by [`JsonConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm),[`JToken.FromObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm), [`ToObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm), and  [`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CreateDefault.htm).

Comment: `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` are not used by [`JsonSerializer.Create()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Create.htm) or `new JsonSerializer()`.  So if some 3rd party app just does `JsonSerializer.Create(myOwnDefaultSettings)` then serializes from and to a stream they won't be taken into account -- which is I believe what asp.net does, and is why it has its own default settings `options.SerializerSettings`.

Comment: If `options.SerializerSettings` are being ignored by asp.net itself when serializing or deserializing *anything returned from Action or coming to Action as a parameter* then I think we need to see a [mcve] for that.