# Json.NET decimal precision loss

Tags: c#, json.net, decimal, linq-to-json

I have an issue with deserializing decimal value.

```
JObject.Parse("{\"available\":8777.831438322572000}")
```

If I type this code in VS under debugger the result is

```
"available": 8777.8314383225716
```

If I try this

```
obj.Value<decimal>("available")
```

the result is `8777.83143832257`

Where am I wrong?
What api methods should I use to get correct results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling decimal values in Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find out that this problem doesn't relate to methods which take destination type as an argument. In case of untyped version method there is a setting which allows to change how json.net treats string with decimal separator. `JsonReader.FloatParseHandling` default value is `FloatParseHandling.Double`
In my case the way to get correct results is:

```
JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(value)) { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal }, null)
```

`JsonSerializer` and `JsonSerializerSettings` contain the same setting.

Comment: You might want to bracket the `JsonTextReader` and `StringReader` in `using` statements.  Practically that doesn't matter with `StringReader` but will be a problem with `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `JObject.Parse("{\"available\":8777.831438322572000}")` is a `double`. The second statement results in a `decimal`.

The `double` has floating point precision, which is not that precise as a `decimal`.

Required reading: [Why Floating-Point Numbers May Lose Precision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx)