# How to deserialize string to JObject without scientific notation in C#

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "{'data': {'someProperty': 0.00001}}";
```

When I parse it to JObject like that

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(str);
```

My jObject looks like this:

```
{"data": {"someProperty": 1E-05}}
```

I need to get rid of scientific notation so that resulting JObject would look like original json.

I managed to do that using later version of Newtonsoft.Json like that:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal };
using (System.IO.TextReader tr = new System.IO.StringReader(str)
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(tr))
{
    var jp = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
    var jObject = JObject.FromObject(jp);
}
```

But I need to achieve the same result using Newtonsoft.Json version 3.5 which does not have a FloatParseHandling property. I guess I need to implement a JsonConverter somehow, but I have no idea how to do that, since my real json is much more complex than the one in example and I need to handle all the float values in it the right way.

So, what would be the right way to get a JObject without a scientific notation for float values using Newtonsoft 3.5?

Comment: String and property wrapper with parsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation

Comment: you can cast the value to decimal, which will return the correct value, and use `ToString()` if you need to work on string values. example `var someProperty = ((decimal) jObject["data"]["someProperty"]).ToString();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following produces the object you are looking for

```
JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(str)) { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal }, null)
```

taken from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205166/json-net-decimal-precision-loss)

EDIT:
JTokenTypes in NewtonSoft v 3.5.8 are limited to Float and Integer (in regards to decimal). There is no decimal type in that version and thus makes it not possilbe to have a decimal value in that JObject.

JTokenTypes from v3 of newtonsoft

```
    None = 0,
    Object = 1,
    Array = 2,
    Constructor = 3,
    Property = 4,
    Comment = 5,
    Integer = 6,
    Float = 7,
    String = 8,
    Boolean = 9,
    Null = 10,
    Undefined = 11,
    Date = 12,
    Raw = 13,
    Bytes = 14
```

The right way to do this would be to upgrade the Newtonsoft package :)

Comment: Thank you. But I indicated that I cannot use FloatParseHandling.

Comment: This is good for deserializing json which only have a property of type float or a string representation of float number. My json is complex with nested objects, properties of different types and arrays. I need it to be deserialized just like JObject.Parse() do, but just the numbers to be deserialized without a scientific notation

Comment: @ИльяИваницкий see my EDIT.

Comment: This would be a good time to formally propose to your leadership that you update versions. It should be pretty easy to show that it would make more business sense to upgrade versions numbers than to have one of their devs spending hours or even days on something the tool they are already using can do off the shelf if they would only keep up with upgrades.

Comment: @ИльяИваницкий does this answer your question

Comment: Well, I guess there is no better option than updating the version. So I will mark this answer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Jawad's provided code is not the best solution because it will end up in memory leaks. `StringReader` and `JsonTextReader` are both implementing the `IDisposable` interface and therefore must be disposed if they are not used anmyore.
Safer code would be:

```
public JObject CustomJObjectLoad(string str)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(str))
    {
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader) { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal })
        {
            return JObject.Load(jsonReader, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your json isn't valid :)
It should have double quotes:

```
{"data": {"someProperty": 0.00001}}
```

But even better, using standard casing, would be:

```
{"Data": {"SomeProperty": 0.00001}}
```

And then, we can do this:

```
var str = "{\"Data\": {\"SomeProperty\": 0.00001}}";
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
var val = myObject.Data.SomeProperty.ToString("0." + new string('#', 339));
```

`val` will then be: `"0.00001"`

(Note: I stole the solution from: [Double to string conversion without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation))

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid creating classes if possible, since I cannot guarantee the exact shape of json.

Comment: I have a complex json with many properties, nested objects, arrays etc. SomeProperty is just for example. I need all float values to be handled correctly.

Comment: Ok, I read the edits to your OP. I understand better now what you are trying to do. You want to change the way doubles are serialized. But, may I ask why? For any math purposes, the scientific notation will still work just fine. I assume you only want to change it for display purposes, right? And if that's the case, why not just do the conversion right before doing the display?

Comment: The usage is not in my competence. I need to provide json for a third party and that is their requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create simple POCO object. and make sure `someProperty` is of type string and then de-serialize the json string

```
var myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(json)
```

Comment: That's pretty much what my answer said too :)