# Deserialize JSON in a controller not working

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have the following controller method in .Net Core (3.1):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateOrders([FromBody]IEnumerable<Order> orders)
```

`Order` is here:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
}
```

From the network tab, the following JSON is being passed through:

```
{"orders":
[
    {"product":"zzzz","ordertotal":"12"},
    {"product":"xxxx","ordertotal":"23"}
]}
```

In the controller method, the data is coming through as null. My guess is that it can't deserialize it properly. Does anyone have any ideas why that could be?

Comment: What _specifically_ is `null`?

Comment: The fact that the name and type of `ordertotal` is different stands out to me.

Comment: You'd also want to not wrap numbers in quotes

Comment: Isn't that an object with a Property "orders" that is a List of Orders rather than a List in itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

1. `OrderTotal` is coming like a string and your model expect decimal
2. you're expecting `IEnumerable<Order>` array of orders but your sending an object that contains a property with an array.

For `2` you can create a new RequestModel like

```
public class OrderRequestModel
{
    public IList<Order> orders { get; set; }
}
```

and change your controller signature like

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateOrders([FromBody]OrderRequestModel order)
```

and for `1` you can change your payload to send `decimal` values instead of `string` and still if you prefer keeping it string from frontend then you should use a converter something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are some problems here:

Your body should be like this in order to match your model:

```
{"orders":
 [
    {"product":"zzzz","orderTotal":12},
    {"product":"xxxx","orderTotal":23}
]}
```

**OR:**

You should define your object with the following way in order to be able to deserialize the object properly:

```
public partial class Order
{
    [JsonProperty("product")]
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ordertotal")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Ordertotal { get; set; }
}
```

In any case, it's better to use the `OrderTotal` instead of `Ordertotal`