# C#: In an object is it possible to convert decimal values to a string or double?

Tags: c#, json, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I have a Json object which I get from rest call and there is no specific format.
Is it possible to iterate through the object and check if any decimal value exists and convert it to a string/double?

I need to pass this object into a couchbaseLite's MutableDocument which doesn't allow any decimals

**Object**

```
{
 "performer": [
    {
      "referedBy": "ABDC",
      "text": "XYZ"
    }
  ],
  "quantity": {
    "value": 100.0, **// --> This should bee converted to "100.0"**
    "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
  },
"range": [
    {
      "low": {
        "value": 0.0, **// --> This should bee converted to "0.0"**
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
      },
      "text": "Total values"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to do it by checking the specific properties and fixing it i.e., check for "quantity", "range" etc. But wondering if there is a better way to iterate through the object i.e., **a generic method that can iterate through the object that can convert the decimals to integer/double as I won't know the exact format of the object beforehand.**

**Code**:

```
private static void UpdateQuantity(JToken result)
        {
            var quantity = (result as JToken)["quantity"];
            if (quantity == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            //update value from deciaml to string in quantity
            string quantityValue = null;
            foreach (JToken token in (result as JToken)["quantity"].Children())
            {
                JProperty ps = token as JProperty;
                if (ps != null && ps.Name.Contains("value"))
                {
                    quantityValue = ps.Value.ToString().Replace(',', '.');
                    ps.Replace(new JProperty("value", quantityValue as object));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What type are you getting when just setting "quantityValue = ps.Value;"?

Comment: `quantityValue = ps.Value.ToString().Replace(',', '.');` Don't do this. What you want is `quantityValue = ps.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` (if you want the value to be a string with the dot as decimal separator.

Comment: @MNDevelopments It's just an object.

Comment: @PMF Thanks. I'll keep that in mind but I want something more generic so I don't have to implement "quantity", "range" etc.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052157/1462295) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work for you

```
foreach (var token in
    obj.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().SelectMany(o =>
        o.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Integer || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Float)))
{
    token.Value = token.Value.ToString();
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5gDtC)

- Take all descendants of the root object, including itself.
- Which are `JObject`
- Select all their properties where...
- ... the JSON type of the property value is either `Integer` or `Float`
- For each one, change the value to be the stringified form of the same value.

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know about `DescendantsAndSelf`. This helps a lot. Thank you!